# Matplotlib python connect two scatter plots with lines for each pair of (x,y) values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am having trouble connecting two sets of points in a scatter plot with each other such that a line (in this example, using dummy data) connects all the 'pre' points with the corresponding 'post' points. The 'marker = 'o-' argument doesn't work for plt. scatter, but does for plt. plot. Suggestions on how to connect the corresponding values? Thanks and hope this question makes sense!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x1 = ["pre"] * 4
x2 = ["post"] * 4
y1 = [0.1, 0.15, 0.13, 0.25]
y2 = [0.85, 0.76, 0.8, 0.9]
plt.scatter(x1, y1, color='y')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, color='g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking this. `for i in range(len(x1)):
    plt.plot([x1[i],x2[i]], [y1[i],y2[i]])`

Comment: yes, this worked great! I also added marker = 'o' so the end points would appear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While @ImportanceOfBeingErnest already gave you the seemingly simplest possible solution, you might be interested in knowing an alternate solution to get what you want. You can use [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html)

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Rest of your code

lines = [[x, list(zip([1]*4, y2))[i]] for i, x in enumerate(zip([0]*4, y1))]
print (lines)
# [[(0, 0.1), (1, 0.85)], [(0, 0.15), (1, 0.76)], [(0, 0.13), (1, 0.8)], [(0, 0.25), (1, 0.9)]]

lc = LineCollection(lines)
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Overkill or duplicate?

Comment: I here had to figure out how to create the list lines here. Rest was based on using linecollection from SO. I admit it’s an overkill and that’s why I started my answer saying that your suggestion was the easiest yet this is just an alternative.  To Be honest, I actually was myself interested in trying to see how one can use line collection in solving this problem ;)

Comment: Hmm, so if this is a question, I'd do `verts = np.c_[np.zeros_like(y1),y1,np.ones_like(y2),y2].reshape(len(x1),2,2)`