# Python - connect two sets of dots in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I created two scatterplots and put them on the same graph. I also want to match the points of the two scatterplots (note that the two scatterplots have the same number of points).

My current code is provided below, and the plot I want to get is sketched at the bottom of this post.

```
plt.scatter(tmp_df['right_eye_x'], tmp_df['right_eye_y'],
            color='green', label='right eye')
plt.scatter(tmp_df['left_eye_x'], tmp_df['left_eye_y'],
            color='cyan', label='left eye')
plt.legend()
```

Here is a fake dataframe you may use, in case you need to do some testing. (My data is of the following format; you may use the last two lines in the code chunk to create the dataframe)

```
timestamp right_eye_x  right_eye_y left_eye_x  left_eye_y
    15        54           22          28          19
    20        56           21          29          21
    25        59           16          28          16   
    30        58           18          31          18   
    35        62           15          33          14


data = {'timestamp':[15,20,25,30,35],
'right_eye_x':[54, 56, 59, 58, 62],
'right_eye_y':[22, 21, 16, 18, 15],
'left_eye_x':[28, 29, 22, 31, 33],
'left_eye_y':[19, 21, 16, 18, 14]}
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I saw this post: [Matplotlib python connect two scatter plots with lines for each pair of (x,y) values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54659559/matplotlib-python-connect-two-scatter-plots-with-lines-for-each-pair-of-x-y-va)
while I am still very confused.

I would appreciate any insights! Thank you!
(If you find any part confusing, please let me know!)

[image: What I want to get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the solution from the comments that is shown in the post you cite.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x1 = [0.19, 0.15, 0.13, 0.25]
x2 = [0.18, 0.5, 0.13, 0.25]
y1 = [0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.2]
y2 = [0.85, 0.76, 0.8, 0.9]

for i in range(len(x1)):     
  plt.plot([x1[i],x2[i]], [y1[i],y2[i]])
```

You can put labels, colors and stuff looking at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html